# Insert transparent circle into gimp

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have this `.png` image in **Gimp** with transparent borders:

[image: cd3.png]

Now I'd like to make the center circle transparent but I'm at a loss and can't find any instructions on-line.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose the Ellipse Select tool <kbd>E</kbd>
2. Begin clicking and dragging from the centre of the inner circle, and then while you are doing this hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. This will constrain the ellipse to a circle with the origin at the centre. You can nudge the circle into place with the arrow keys if you want to adjust it slightly, or click and drag the selection handles.
3. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and the circle will be removed
4. Finally do *Select > None* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, to release the selection

[image]

To resave as PNG, do *File > Export As*.  Don't forget to give your edit a new file name if you don't want to overwrite the original.

Comment: Best written quick answer with illustration I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Erase tool to erase it manually, or select that white space using the Fuzzy Select tool and then Clear it with either the Edit menu option or by pressing `Del`.